# Java Spring: Enum keys in (LinkedHash)Map are not ordered

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

My entity `Mealplan` has an `mealsPerWeek` property as a LinkedHashMap.

```
@Entity
public class Mealplan {

@Id
private int id;

@ManyToMany
private Map<Weekday, Meal> mealsPerWeek = new LinkedHashMap<>();

public Map<Weekday, Meal> getMealsPerWeek() {
    return mealsPerWeek;
}

}
```

The key of the map property is `Weekday`and is an enumeration:

```
public enum Wochentag {
    Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday
}
```

Now I expect that in my API the Meals get displayed in the correct order of the enum. But it is displayed pretty random:

```
{
id: 1,
mealsPerWeek: {
  Tuesday: {
   id: 3,
   name: "Salad",
   preis: 3,
   art: "vegan"
},
  Monday: {
   id: 4,
   name: "Linsensuppe",
   preis: 23.5,
   art: "vegan"
},
```

How do I order it in my REST API so it displays the keys in its correct order?

Edit: I insert objects via `data.sql` on  every application startup and realised, that everytime the order is differnet.

Source Code: https://gitlab.com/joshua.olberg/java-spring-backend

Comment: LinkedHashMap is ordered by the order in which keys were inserted into the map. It is not sorted. Do you expect it to be sorted when creating a new object or when querying for Mealplan?

Comment: The problem will be that although the iteration order is the order of population, population is done by the JPA implementation - Hibernate or whatever you are using. This isn't an answer as I'm not sure off the top of my head how to apply a sort order to a Map field in an entity - someone will know though.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers. So, is it maybe better to sort the keys on client side? @Lesiak yes I am expecting it to be sorted, when creating a new object. but it will always be the same order and always be one object per key.

Comment: You can use order value for enum and use treemap with comparator on order value.

Comment: You say thevorderbis wrong when creating a new object. That is surprising. Can you please show us how you build it?

Comment: is "thevorderbis" a mistake? :)

Comment: I meant ”the order is wrong”. Silly tablet.

Comment: I am inserting new objects with an SQL file in its correct order. What I noticed is that on every restart of the application, the order is different. may this be a hint?

Comment: Show repository code

Comment: hey there - I have added my source code on the opening code but you may be confused, because some keywords are in german.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when loading the map (and generally, all collections) from the db, hibernate uses its own collection types.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/domain/collections.html

> Hibernate uses its own collection implementations which are enriched with lazy-loading, caching or state change detection semantics. For this reason, persistent collections must be declared as an interface type. The actual interface might be java.util.Collection, java.util.List, java.util.Set, java.util.Map, java.util.SortedSet, java.util.SortedMap or even other object types (meaning you will have to write an implementation of org.hibernate.usertype.UserCollectionType).
>
> As the following example demonstrates, it’s important to use the interface type and not the collection implementation, as declared in the entity mapping.
>
> Example 1. Hibernate uses its own collection implementations
>
> ```
> @Entity(name = "Person")
> public static class Person {
>     @Id
>     private Long id;
>
>   @ElementCollection
>     private List<String> phones = new ArrayList<>();
>
>   public List<String> getPhones() {
>         return phones;
>     }
> }
>
> Person person = entityManager.find( Person.class, 1L );
> //Throws java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
> ArrayList<String> phones = (ArrayList<String>) person.getPhones();
> ```

Therefore:

```
private Map<Weekday, Meal> mealsPerWeek = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

will be replaced by PersistentMap.
That is why initializing a Map with EnumMap or TreeMap fails.

You want Hibernate to use PersistentSortedMap, and for that

- use a correct interface `SortedMap`
- add `@SortNatural` or `@SortComparator`

Comment: So will Hibernate honour a SortedMap declaration? I guess that doesn't help as it would define the sort order anyway. How annoying!

Comment: @Chris: you can define the sort order by annotations (SortNatural or SortComparator, there was also Sort, but it is deprecated)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! fun fact: using @SortNatural without changing other code or interfaces made it work too. Do you know why? If it works, can I keep using LinkedHashMap?

Comment: I encourage you to keep interface, your implementation and hibernate implementation in sync. This way 1. New instances (created with `new` in your code which are using iplementation you defined, not hibernate ones) will behave consistently to ones loaded from the db. 2. The instrumentation is already confusing, I bet people maintaining this code will be really grateful if you add inconsistent types on top of that (you are not in obfuscated code competition, are you?)

Comment: One point is, that I can not use the SortedMap Interface with @ManyToMany relations. Spring always says `'Many To Many' attribute type should be java.util.Map`. And no, Im not in code competition. :)

Comment: Meh. Does `Map` on the left hand and `TreeMap` on the right side work?

Comment: @Lesiak Yes. TreeMap does work (with the `@SortNatural` annotation) - I noticed that the HashMap works, but then my `@PostMapping` does not work anymore - I guess I'll stay with the TreeMap.

Comment: Happy that you've got it running. TreeMap is implements SortedMap, which extends Map, it is pretty clear how the code will behave.

Answer (score 0):

EnumMap may help you here. Iteration order is based on declared order in the Enum - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html

Comment: I made it: private `Map<Weekday, Meal> mealsPerWeek = new EnumMap<Weekday, Meal>(Weekday.class);` and it still did not sort it. :/

Comment: Ah damn, thought that would do it - sorry.

Comment: Quite curious now why it doesn't work but don't have my laptop handy. I'd be tempted to stick a breakpoint in ObjectMapper to see how it is serialising that map, or just look at the source code.

Comment: Hmm, a quick look at source on GitHub with my phone makes me think debug would be easier to get to the right place.

Comment: hey there - I have added my source code on the opening code but you may be confused, because some keywords are in german.

Comment: I was thinking debug in ObjectMapper when it serialises you entity to create the JSON